# UIImageView animate with duration, together with animation images

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I just started iOS development and am learning to Swift and Xcode.  I have an UIImageView object in a view controller and would like to move this UIImageView across the screen while it is toggling between two images.  Here's the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var anImageView: UIImageView!

@IBAction func beginAnimation(sender: AnyObject) {

    let imgListArray:[AnyObject] = [UIImage(named: "img1.png")!, UIImage(named: "img2.png")!]
    anImageView.animationImages = imgListArray
    anImageView.animationDuration = 0.5
    anImageView.image = UIImage(named: "img1.png")
    anImageView.startAnimating()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(4.0, animations: {
        self.anImageView.center = CGPoint(x: 600, y: 600)
        }, completion: {finished in
            self.anImageView.center = CGPoint(x:80,y:80)})
}
```

The problem is with the co-ordinates.  The UIImageView starts off-screen and does not end at (80,80).  The toggling is fine.

I guess I have to transform the co-ordinates to the superview(?) space, but my attempts to do this have not been successful.  For example, I tried the convertPoint function, but was not successful.

Any guidance is highly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using constraints to position the image view initially? If so you need to adjust the constraints and not the frame location, then animate the constraint change by putting `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` in the animation block.

Comment: Thanks, Rory.  Yes, the auto layout and size classes option were both checked.  I unchecked them, and the behaviour is as expected.  Best wishes.

Comment: I think you have just delayed the issue turning off constraints. It is better to embrace them I have found or the future will be full of hurt for you. In your case the principle is the same, just use constraints instead of direct frame manipulation and change the constraint values. You can add constraints as IBOutlets to let you change their values in code easily.

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified clearly what you *want* to do, so let's concentrate on what this code *does* do:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(4.0, animations: {
    self.anImageView.center = CGPoint(x: 600, y: 600)
}, completion: {finished in
    self.anImageView.center = CGPoint(x:80,y:80)
})
```

That code says:

1. No matter where it is now, start the image view moving from that point towards (600,600) (which, unless you are on an iPad, will be offscreen).
2. When it gets there, make it *jump* from (600,600) to (80,80).

That's what you are saying. So if that isn't what you want, don't say that!

Comment: Yes, I am working on an iPad application.  Again, this is just a test code to make the UIImageView move, while toggling through the  image array, and make it do something on animation completion.  The UIImageView is positioned in the View Controller at (80,80) at the beginning.

Comment: Okay, so I would expect it to move slowly from (80,80) to (600,600) and then jump back to (80,80). But you have not said clearly how what you are seeing differs from that. Of course there are a lot of other things at play here - the size of the image view (remember, those coordinates are the image view's _center_), its content mode, whether you have positioned it using auto layout, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Matt.  It was the auto layout issue.  Once that option was unchecked, along with size classes, the behaviour was expected.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking auto layout option solved the problem for now.  But the right approach is to leave auto layout on and animate constraints.  Will post a solution once I get it working.

Comment: Okay, but that's the wrong solution. You are not solving the problem; you are turning your back on it. You need to use auto layout. The right approach is to learn how to do animation in the presence of auto layout - for example, animate constraints instead of animating position, or remove this view from auto layout temporarily and then put it back again.

Comment: Thanks.  I will certainly learn more on auto layout and animate constraints. I edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Why not delete your question and start again, or edit your question, so that instead of waving your hands, you ask how to perform this positional animation properly? Even better, search Stack Overflow and don't bother asking any question; the topic of how to animate in the presence of auto layout has been discussed heavily here.